# Delphi TfdQuery, how to get the parameters that were passed for a query?

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm trying to implement a log of all the SQL statements that were executed. For this, I need to retrieve the instruction that was passed including the parameters. Unfortunately the statement:

vText:string;
vText: = fdquery.sql.text;

Returns without parameter values. Does anyone have any other way to generate the log?

Comment: FireDAC offers its own built-in [Tracing and Monitoring](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Tracing_and_Monitoring_(FireDAC)) capabilities, which includes logging SQL and parameters being sent to databases. Have a look at the [FDMonitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FDMonitor) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the Params property like this:

```
for var I := 0 to FDQuery1.ParamCount - 1 do
    vText := VText + 'Param[' + I.ToString + '] = "' +
             FDQuery1.Params[I].AsString + '"';
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as good and up-vote it if it fits your needs. If it doesn't, ask clarifications.

Comment: You also can get the name of param as well. Like this: `vText := Format('%s%s = "%s"; ', [vText, query.Params[i].Name, query.Params[i].AsString]);`